# Is there a way to control who the last modified person is on a sharepoint list item

Tags: sharepoint-2013

For example: If Bob is a content owner and needs to open the item to view more detailed information for example, when Bob closes that item his name should not replace the name of the non-content owner who last modified that item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter the view and checkout metadata. You can see who modified last.